# GMap.NET WPF Marker timer update

Tags: wpf, multithreading, gmap.net

I have very little experience using threads so I might be missing some pretty basic infomration in my logic.

Anyway, I'm trying to update a GMapMarker based on 1000ms timer.

My Timer start:

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerEvent;
aTimer.Interval = 1000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

My update code:

```
int _positionIncriment = 0;
private  void OnTimerEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    PointLatLng p = m_debugPath[_positionIncriment];
    _gpsMarker.Position = p;
    _positionIncriment++;

    _gmap.ForceUpdateOverlays();

    if(_positionIncriment >= m_debugPath.Count)
    {
        _positionIncriment = 0;
    }
}
```

As I step through this block, it stops at the ForceUpdateOverlays and never progresses further.
As far as I can tell the render functions of GMap is within its own thread which might be causing issue.. but as I said, only have a basic understanding of threading I'm a bit lost.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DispatcherTimer instead of Timer. Its Tick event is fired in the UI thread:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
...

aTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
aTimer.Tick += OnTimerEvent;
aTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
aTimer.IsEnabled = true; // or aTimer.Start();
...

private void OnTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to invoke the Dispatcher before running my code.
I don't know is this the the 'correct' way to solve this problem, but the end result is what i was desiring.

Hope this helps someone else.

```
int _positionIncrement = 0;
private  void OnTimerEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        PointLatLng p = m_debugPath[_positionIncrement];
        _gps.Position = p;
        _positionIncrement++;

        _gmap.ForceUpdateOverlays();

        if(_positionIncrement >= m_debugPath.Count)
        {
            _positionIncrement = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Or just use a DispatcherTimer.